# Expression.Error: 2 arguments were passed to a function which expects 1

Tags: excel, vba, api, powerbi, powerquery

I have been trying to build an automated vba tool to pull API data but kept having below error from Power Query...

`Expression.Error: 2 arguments were passed to a function which expects 1. Details: Pattern= Arguments=[List]`

Kept looking up the solution but could not really find the right reason...

Here is my code as below

```
let

    Parameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameter"]}[Content],

    URL= Parameter[Column1]{0},

    Source = Json.Document(Web.Page(Web.Contents(URL), [
        Headers =[#"Authorization"="Basic ENCODE64PASSWORDS"]])),
    
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    Value = #"Converted to Table"{0}[Value],
    results = Value[results],


    #"Converted to Table1" = Table.FromList(results, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table1", "Column1", {"path", "upsertable"}, {"path", "upsertable"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Column1", each ([upsertable] = true)),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"path", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

I am no professional coder but just started to feel interested in coding world.
This code is mostly just mixture of copy and paste all over the web haha
So please understand im only a beginner with a baby step and forgive my ignorance if this is actually a simple matter..or if I dont really understand your reply well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly sure it is this line. Try changing it to the following:

```
Source = Json.Document(Web.Page(Web.Contents(URL, [
        Headers =[#"Authorization"="Basic ENCODE64PASSWORDS"]]))),
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the help! It seems like you were correct. But after I got connected, how it says "Expression.Error: The 'Authorization' header is only supported when connecting anonymously. These headers can be used with all authentication types: Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cache-Control, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since, Prefer, Range, Referer" I googled out with the error message, but ppl say its bascially saying my auth key couldn’t be authenticated....? it works just fine with post man tho.....

Comment: That is a different question. Please mark this as solved and start a new question.